# Проблема с текстом в HTML

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите, как правильно решать такие проблемы, когда текстовые блоки наезжают друг на друга, я обнулил им отступы, но как сделать так, чтобы они шли строго друг за другом, и, подскажите, из-за чего так происходит? И, подскажите, почему заголовок так сплюснулся?

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

div,
span,
ul,
li,
a,
button,
article {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 1px solid yellow;
}

.templates {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header__title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__heading">
        <h1 class="header__title">
          Основы HTML5 и CSS3
        </h1>
        <p class="header__description">
          Этот сайт я создал специально для обучения. Здесь я буду проходить теорию и практику верстки средствами HTML5 и CSS3. А так же FlexBox.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Не сплюснулся, а равен высоте строки, которую ты задал в body и которая наследуется дочерними элементами.

Comment: Спасибо, все сработало. Очень помогли!